# Set docker image to use for job execution

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a docker runner. This asked me to set the default docker image to be used for execution of jobs. How do I override this default from the .gitlab-ci.yml file per job?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out:

```
job1:
  image: <image to use, overriding the default set by the runner>
  script: "<do something>"
  tags:
    - general
```